# Firebase Promise Order in forEach

Tags: firebase, promise

The below code works in order like this

```
-->then 1 
-->then 2
-->then 3
-->then 3 ends
-->then 4
-->then 5
--> x
--> y
--> x
--> y
-->then 6
```

But I want it to be in order like this:

```
-->then 1 
-->then 2
-->then 3
--> x
--> y
--> x
--> y
-->then 3 ends
-->then 4
-->then 5
-->then 6
```

This is the code:
The problem is in forEach.
If I have once("value") stuff in forEach, I couldn't manage waiting the result of it then proceeding to "then 4"

```
   let massUpdate={};
let licenseLength=0;
let refOfferLength =admin.database().ref()...
refOfferLength.once("value")
    .then(lengthSnapshot=>{
        console.log(" then :1 ");
        //....
    }).then(snap=>{
    console.log(" then :2 ");
    let ref = admin.database().ref()....
    return ref.once("value");
}).then(ref=>{
    console.log(" then :3 ");
    ref.forEach(function(pSnapshot){
        let pId = pSnapshot.key;
        let pPath = pSnapshot.val();

        let refP = admin.database().ref().child("asd").child(event.params.userId).child(pPath).child(pId);
        refP.once("value").then(snap=>{
            console.log(" then :x ");
            //.....


            let path_license = "asd/" + event.params.userId+"/"+urunPath+"/"+urunId+"/license";
            let val_license = "open";
            //....

            massUpdate[path_license]=val_license;

        }).then(snap=>{console.log(" then :y ");});

    });
    console.log(" then :3 ends");


}).then(snap=>{// 
    console.log(" then :4 ");
    let pathOffersAndUsers = "kpss_offers_and_users/"+event.params.offerId+"/"+event.params.userId;
    let valOfferDetails = {"created_date": (moment().utcOffset(3).format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"))};
    massUpdate[pathOffersAndUsers]=valOfferDetails;

    return true;

}).then(snap=>{// 
    console.log(" then :5 ");

    let ref = admin.database().ref();
    return ref.update(massUpdate);

}).then(snap=>{
    console.log(" then :6 ");

    console.log(" Done : "+ event.params.userId + " : "+ event.params.offerId);


}).catch(function (error){console.log(" E : "+error+" : "+ event.params.userId + " : "+ event.params.offerId);});
```

Comment: Uh, [don't use `forEach` with promises](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572) (or otherwise)?

Answer (score 0):

In a `then` callback you should *return* a promise when you want to delay the next `then` callback in the `then` chain until that promise resolves.

You *do* have promises in your `forEach` loop, but their return value is lost in oblivion. You can chain them and return the resulting promise with `reduce`:

```
return ref.reduce(function(prom, pSnapshot){ // return(!) a promise from reduce
    let pId = pSnapshot.key;
    let pPath = pSnapshot.val();

    let refP = admin.database().ref().child("asd").child(event.params.userId).child(pPath).child(pId);
    return prom.then(function () { // return(!) the promise, chained to the previous
        return refP.once("value");
    }).then(snap=>{ 
        console.log(" then :x ");
        //.....
        let path_license = "asd/" + event.params.userId+"/"+urunPath+"/"+urunId+"/license";
        let val_license = "open";
        //....
        massUpdate[path_license]=val_license;
    }).then(snap=>{console.log(" then :y ");});
}, Promise.resolve()) // start the promise chain with a resolved promise
.then(function () { // Chain one more `then` callback to report
    console.log(" then :3 ends");
});
```

Depending on whether your loop-promises have to wait for the previous one to resolve or not, you could also use `Promise.all`, which allows to create the promises all in parallel:

```
return Promise.all(ref.map(function(pSnapshot){ // pass an array of promises
    let pId = pSnapshot.key;
    let pPath = pSnapshot.val();

    let refP = admin.database().ref().child("asd").child(event.params.userId).child(pPath).child(pId);
    return refP.once("value").then(snap=>{ 
        console.log(" then :x ");
        //.....
        let path_license = "asd/" + event.params.userId+"/"+urunPath+"/"+urunId+"/license";
        let val_license = "open";
        //....
        massUpdate[path_license]=val_license;
    }).then(snap=>{console.log(" then :y ");});
}))
.then(function () { // Chain one more `then` callback to report
    console.log(" then :3 ends");
});
```

I just mentioned the relevant part of the code, but you could (and should) move the last `then` call one level up in the main chain.